# Angular2, Zones vs ChangeDetectorRef to force ui update on received data

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 applcation. It connects to a SignalR service and receives regular updates (every 10 seconds). These updates are emitted from an angualr service to the component via an emitter.
I noticed that the ui wasn't always updating when new data came in, sometimes there was a delay of 10 seconds or so.

To get around this I added a call to detectChanges() in the component...

```
this._signalrService.onGetData.subscribe((data: any) => {
            // update some data properties
            this._cd.detectChanges();
        });
```

I have also used zones to achieve the same thing...

```
this._signalrService.onGetData.subscribe((data: any) => { 
            this._ngZone.run(() => {
            // update some data properties
            });
        });
```

Basically I want to force a ui update when the component receives data.

Are either of these ways the correct to do this? Should the zone be placed somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the correct way.

- use `this._cd.detectChanges` when the update is local to the component that contains the code in your question
- use `this._ngZone.run(...)` when the update affects other components as well. A common example is using `router.navigate(...)`
- instead of `this._ngZone.run(...)` `ApplicationRef.tick()` can be used as well. It causes change detection for the whole application to be run.